# Update Macbook with latest OS X

Tags: macos, iphone, macbook, xcode

I have a macbook running OS X v10.5.8.

1. What is the latest version of Mac OS X for the macbook pro?
2. How can I update my OS to use latest version of XCode?

Answer (score 3):

There will be a volley of responses saying this should be on Server Fault, but since it is related to XCode I'll answer it here.

The latest version of OS X is 10.6.2 and is known as Snow Leopard.

The latest version of the iPhone SDK with XCode needs 10.5.7 for the Leopard version and 10.6.0 for the Snow Leopard version. Make sure you download the correct one for your OS.

To update your OS to the latests minor revision, do Apple -> Software Update. To update from Leopard (10.5) to Snow Leopard (10.6) you need to buy a upgrade from apple.com, or your local software store. The upgrade is $29 for a license.